# Angular material 6 table

Tags: angular, angular-material, behaviorsubject

I'm using Angular material's table component. The problem I'm currently facing is that after I add or delete rows, I want to update the contents of the table automatically. I want to set a flag in the table. If the data is deleted or added, Allows the table to know that it sends a request to the server whenever it detects a change. Looking at the material API, there is a [viewChange](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable) property that can be applied to the problem I am currently encountering?

Comment: Do you use MatTableDataSource ? Update `MatTableDataSource.data` and it will automaticly refresh your content.

Comment: I use MatTableSource, but the add and delete actions are performed in different components. How to let the table know that the add or delete action has been completed, and then update the data

Comment: Are mat-table component and (add/delete) component displayed in the parent component? Or the (add/delete) component is mat-table component's children?

Comment: the view(table) component and the action(component) is sibling , but i have solved my problem by use `BehaviorSubject` in service. When the action(add or delete)  is submit to change property `viewChange` ( `boolean`) and the view subscribe the `viewChange` . If `viewChange` is true , view send the request to server get the data immediately

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries?file=app%2Fmembers%2Fmembers.component.ts). It is easier than your approach.

For deleting:

```
// Remove the deleted row from the data table. Need to remove from the downloaded data first.
  private deleteRowDataTable (recordId, idColumn, paginator, dataSource) {
    this.dsData = dataSource.data;
    const itemIndex = this.dsData.findIndex(obj => obj[idColumn] === recordId);
    dataSource.data.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    dataSource.paginator = paginator;
  }
```

For updating:

```
// ---- UPDATE ----  Called from edit-member.component.html

  private update() {
    if (this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.valid) {
      this.formValue = this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.value;
      this.httpService.updateRecord(this.membersUrl, this.formValue)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          // Update the table data view for the changes.
          this.updateDatatableService.updateDataTable(
            result, this.recordId, this.idColumn, this.paginator, this.dataSource, this.formValue);
          this.success();
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
          this.handleError(err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

I don't have this for adding but you get the idea and can add rows the same way.

Hope this helps.